# PHP Netbeans 6.8 subversion integration (Windows 7)

Tags: php, svn, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans 6.8 for PHP (under Windows 7) and the subversion integration doesn't work. I am able to checkout a module but I don't see the subversion features in the menus or the outine in the editor left margin that shows the changes in the files. I am using it under Ubuntu with no problems.

Did any of you experimented the same problem? If yes, were you able to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running it on a 64-bit machine?  Also, did you do the checkout from within NetBeans?

Comment: Yes I am running it on 64-bit and I was able to checkout within NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is workng now, seems that in Windows the project MUST be in My Documents\NetBeansProject folder for the Subversion integration to work. I don't know if this is a bug but it is not behaving like this in Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help Cryo.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Plugins and make sure the Subversion plugin is installed under the Installed tab.  If it is make sure it's enabled as well.  If not you'll need to install that plugin to bring the context menus into NetBeans.  Once you get those try and run any Subversion command (like update) and if the underlying SVN installation hasn't been completed it should walk you through finishing it.

Comment: The plugin is installed and enabled. I tried both checkout from Netbeans and Tortoise, the problem is my project doesn't seem to be recognize as subversion module. I also installed the svn binaries and linked them correctly in Netbeans options.

Are you using Win7 64bits? It seems that I am isolated case... but I can't find what's wrong in my setup.

Comment: @gimpe Yes, I'm currently running 6.8 on Win 7 64-bit and it works for me in NetBeans as well as in TortoiseSVN.  Does Tortoise not even give you extended commands?  Did you perhaps do an export instead of a checkout?  An export will download the repository but not maintain the linking.  I'd suggest redoing your checkout if possible.

Comment: @Cryo In Tortoise everything works fine (update, checkout, etc.) so my checkout is OK. I tried many times to do a fresh checkout and I even reinstalled Netbeans. Still not luck. But thanks for confirming that it should work with Win7 :)

Comment: @gimpe Very strange.  Do you see Subversion in the list under the Team menu?  If you open up Tools -> Options and then go to the Miscellaneous tab and then the Versioning tab do you see Subversion in the list of Versioning Systems?  Is your 'Path to the SVN executable' specified in that options screen?  Mine is blank.  If you run `svn --version` from a DOS prompt does it work properly?  This works for me.

Comment: I have subversion in the Team menu and I can run <code>svn --version works</code). I just added the plugin "Bundles subversion client for windows" and it is still not working.

Comment: @gimpe wow, I have no clue what's going on then.  +1 to question to try and get some more answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the Netbeans svn plugin doesn't work, you can install a commandline subversion client like sliksvn and then netbeans should find the commandline tools.

Also, you should check your permissions on the folder you are working in. You probably don't have the permission required to use subversion in the folder that you are trying to use it in.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was that the project needs to be in the NetBeansProject folder...